# Cannot create object from file included in php

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFWfq.png)

Hi. I have some files that included like the picture. But after include, I cannot create any object. What did I do wrong. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image you provided.
$attribute = Model/....  //not
initialized

Should be something like..
$attribute = new Model()->attribute():

Or
$attribute = new Attribute();

or if declared static
$attribute = Attribute();
And in your include i don't think the vendor will use Database.php.php